# How to create query mysql in jquery like a clone

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

i have a query in php :

```
<div class="col-md-7" id="col_bahan">
  <select name="bahan[]" id="bahan" class="form-control bahan_asli">
    <option value="0">--pilih--</option>
    <?php
      $qry = $db->query("SELECT * FROM bahan");
      while ($bahan = $qry->fetch_array()) {
        $qry2 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM warna WHERE id_warna='$bahan[id_warna]'");
        $warna = $qry2->fetch_array();
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $bahan['id_bahan']; ?>"><?php echo $bahan['id_bahan']; ?> - <?php echo $bahan['nm_bahan'] . ' Warna ' . $warna['nm_warna']; ?></option> 
    <?php
      }
    ?>
  </select>
</div>
```

I want to copy/clone this code in jquery, then I render element in HTML. I don't like using `.clone()` for it,

Comment: Could you please explain a bit more about what you mean by "copy/clone this code in jquery"? Also, you may want to consider using a JOIN instead of a nested query inside of a loop.

Comment: i want to create element like "$("#div").append('code on above');

Comment: Which code above? Each of the <option> elements?

Comment: all that `div#col_bahan`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
$("#div").html($("#col_bahan").html());
```